# How to develop and deploy a back-end server for my Android application?

Tags: android, database, server, hosting, backend

I am developing a voting application based on Android. This app will be used to create user accounts, receive notifications and caste vote.
I want to develop a back-end server for this application which will also have an Administrator interface to create new voting events. I want to know what all options I have to implement this project.
The server must maintain user account records in a secure manner, send out one-time-passwords from email, have sessions implemented for users logging in from the Android App, send out notifications about upcoming events to the app.

What back-end technology, database, parsing(for communication between server and android application), encryption(for secure communication) should I use to make this possible?

I also want to know how would I be able to host this server, both on a local virtual machine as well as on an online hosting.

Comment: Hi again @Abhimanyu Singh. Just checking if my answer successfully answered your question? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This prevents this question from showing up on the 'Unanswered' tab. If not, can you please list any problems you're still facing, so that I can try to help you further. Cheers!

Comment: Hi! Yes, it did. I wasn't aware of this checkbox thing as I am new to stack overflow. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of your project is far too large if you're wanting sessions, administration views, E-mail integration, encryption, etc., without even knowing how it would all interact, or even what language to use.

As for what languages / services you would need, it varies for each task:

- For administration views, you're probably looking at either ASP.NET or PHP with a CMS.
- In terms of security, you'd want either MySQLi, or preferably, PDO. Make sure to read up on how to prevent things like LFI, RFI, SQLi, and XSS if you want semi-decent security.
- Both ASP.NET and PHP can handle sessions, and they're fairly easy to understand in either language, so that wouldn't be too much of a concern.
- While you can send out E-mails directly using scripts like PHP's `mail()` function, you probably want a system that can easily monitor things like how often users click on certain links, where the people who click the links are located, what campaigns are most effective, etc. For that, you'd want a service like MailChimp, Marketo, or Pardot.
- As for how to have the back-end interact with the front-end, you're working with Android, so you're probably working with Java. That means you would be limited to functions like `HttpMethod`. Having said that, you can create plain HTML applications, or use a service like PhoneGap. In either of those situations, you have AJAX at your disposal, which will make things a lot easier.
- For hosting, simply do a Google search for 'web hosting service'. There's literally thousands of decent hosts. Some have better pricing than others, but some have better features. I can't really recommend any brilliant ones, as they all meet different needs. To host locally, you'll want either IIS, or WAMP / LAMP depending on whether you are running Windows or Linux.

If you're not familiar with almost every term that I've mentioned, then the scope of your project is too large, and you'll definitely want to scale back.

I don't mean to scare you off, just making sure you're aware of just how difficult it would be to put all of that together :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I have a team of 4 people to work on this project, so scalability won't be much of an issue.

Regarding developing the back-end, I was considering Django Framework because it provides easy administration, but wasn't sure if it would be the best choice for my project.

Comment: Django is certainly rather powerful, and can certainly create things like admin views. Keep in mind that it runs on Python. Ultimately, you want to go with a language that your developers feel comfortable with. The back-end and front-end would be very separate, and as such, you can pick almost *any* back-end language. If you only need to load webpages in your app, you could consider something like PhoneGap or Cordova to target multiple platforms. If you're specifically after Android, you could always check out [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Comment: Yes the team is indeed comfortable with Python.
We don't actually need to load webpages in my app, we want to fetch and validate the data on the server through the app, login users, etc.